# Generate list from file directory

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a mock media player - like an extremely basic youtube, which allows the user to select the video from a list, and then plays it in an embedded player.

So far I've got the video player playing videos from a list, but I have to manually edit that list if anything changes, rather than it getting updated automatically - which is what I want.

The file structure I have is:

```
dest/
    index.html
    favicon.png
    video/
        movie.mp4
        rabbit.mp4
```

and what I basically want is for the user to be able to choose between the `movie.mp4` and `rabbit.mp4` files (and the rest that will be added when it's actually being used - of which I currently don't know the names of).

I've read that it's not possible with just javascript to access files - for security reasons. That makes sense to me when dealing with the user's files, but not the same directory the html is in! Especially when I only want read-only access. But if it is in fact not possible - which seems likely - could someone let me know what they think is the fastest way to do this?

`<input type="file" multiple/>` doesn't work for me as I need to use a specific directory, not a user selected one.

I am using HTML and Javascript, and due to limitations on the target machine, cannot use PHP. I'd rather avoid server stuff if at all possible. I've never used jquery or ajax, but if it's necessary I can give it a go (although I don't actually know if they're available either).

Thanks,
Adam

Comment: You can't do that. At least with the technologies you are using

Comment: HTML and javascript run on the client's browser, the files you are talking about reside on the server. Therefore, you need some code which runs on the server to enumerate that directory and list the files within. Not possible with client-side only code.

Comment: @Jamiec Why can I access the video files from the "server" side in the embed code though?

Comment: @AdamBourke - The same way you can hyperlink to an HTML file which resides on a server - doesnt mean I can enumerate all html files hosted on a server from client-side code.